# cakephp CSS suddenly has stopped working

Tags: css, cakephp

So I've been working on a website recently, and was messing around with the pages controller, to try to figure out how to create dynamic pages. I couldn't for the life of me figure out what was wrong with the setup I had going, so I decided to revert to the default pages_controller.php in /cake, deleting mine.

I created a view in /pages called philosophy.ctp, and visited both area51.owlhouse/philosophy and area51.owlhouse/pages/philosophy and neither worked. So I decided to use a fresh install with my app and database in place- essentially just replacing /cake, index.php, /plugins and /vendors.

I reload my front page and it's just text. I have a theme for the site but it's just not registering. Same with the default theme, nothing works.

rewrite_module is on. What is wrong with my site? Ever since replacing the system files in cake CSS refuses to load. HELP!

Comment: Start by inspecting the request using Firebug or Web Inspector and tell us what you get instead of the CSS file or if you see any errors.

Comment: Look at the source and see whether the CSS files are being linked. Copy the URL to your browser and check whether they load the CSS or an error page

Comment: By default, mac doesn't show hidden files in finder.

When I copied the new version from finder to coda, the .htaccess was ignored.

imma fool.

Comment: you should post that as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding this for newbies, as I've been asked this 20 times over the last year while bringing new devs onto Cake.

This is most commonly caused by Apache rewrite rules not working.

**1. Verify that your rewrite rules are in place.**

If you have a default setup using the .htaccess files included with Cake, verify that they are in the correct location(s):

```
/app/webroot/.htaccess
/.htaccess
```

Note: If you're doing this, you should consider moving the rewrite rules to your virtual host definition and pointing the root to /app/webroot/.  A good walkthrough may be found here: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rynop/2010/09/10/boost_performance_by_removing_htaccess_plus_multi-site_with_virtualdocumentroot

Alternatively if you've moved the rewrite rules to your virtual host configuration, verify that the rules are set up correctly.

**2. Verify that mod_rewrite is enabled in Apache.**